# CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations is getting called many times

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

`didUpdateLocations` is getting called many times. so how i can handle stop this. I tried using `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` in `didUpdateLocations` but it is not working fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //for Authorisation from the User.
    isAuthorizedtoGetUserLocation()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func isAuthorizedtoGetUserLocation() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse     {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
    marker.title = "name"
    marker.map = mapView

}
```

Udated Code with error

```
func locationManager( _ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager = nil // Here it is giving error "Cannot assign to value: 'manager' is a 'let' constant"

    var newLocation: CLLocation? = locations.last
    var locationAge: TimeInterval? = -(newLocation?.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow)!
    if Double(locationAge!) > 5.0 {
        return
    }
    if Double((newLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!) < 0 {
        return
    }


    //manager = nil
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
    marker.title = "name"
    marker.map = mapView

}
```

Comment: How are you sure that startUpdatingLocation() is being called more than once? From the look of your code, it should only be called once, each time you load the view.

Comment: In that case, that's expected behavior. That method is called, at a frequency determined by your kCLLocationAccuracy. See @anbu's answer for some clarification about how to set it. Basically, the higher your accuracy, the more often that method is called in the delegate, and the more power your phone uses (GPS eats up battery very quickly).

Comment: Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. It's disrespectful to people reading to make them read through code that has nothing to do with what you're asking (e.g. all the map and marker code in your question)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set CLLocation manager's distanceFilter property as below :

```
/* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
 * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f; // you can change as per your require ment
```

Answer (score 2):

Set property `distanceFilter` to the constant distance max `CLLocationDistanceMax` to indicate that a new update should be triggered only after the device moves a significantly large distance.

Answer (score -3):

Another approach is this.
My app I need to upload the location when changed.
Even though I declare distance filter like this:

> locationManager.distanceFilter = 300

When you first crate CLLocationManager or call startUpdatingLocation() it may called multiple times.

so I put them in a task queue like this:

```
     if let locationUploadTask = self.locationTask { // if there is a task waiting, cancel it 
            locationUploadTask.cancel()
        }

     self.locationTask = DispatchWorkItem { //create a new task for upload
            //do your task
        }

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1, execute: self.locationTask!) //execute the task 1 second after
```

this code forces your code to wait 1 second. If there is a new location update in a second, cancels the current task, starts waiting 1 second again.